# Combine Regex searches into one match

Tags: regex

I am trying to set up a Regex which should combine two searches into one full match.

My demo String is:

```
Name Klein Vorname Marvin
```

The Regex should find: `Marvin Klein`

The names can be different. Does anybody know a way how I can get this to work?

This is how far I already got: `^(?=^Name)(?=.*$)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Python, using tagged groups and general search for alphabetic characters:

```
import re

demo_str = "Name Klein Vorname Marvin"

pattern = r"""
    (?:[\w]+)           # Skip the first string ('Name')
    \s+?                # One or more whitespaces
    (?P<last>[\w]+)     # Tagged group 'first'
    \s+?                # One or more whitespaces
    (?:[\w]+)           # Skip the second string ('Vorname')
    \s+?                # One or more whitespaces
    (?P<first>[\w]+)    # Tagged group 'last'
    """

res = re.search(pattern, demo_str, flags = re.X) # re.X handles multi-line patterns

res.group("last") # 'Klein'
res.group("first") # 'Marvin'
```

EDIT: You can reformat to get your output pretty quickly.  I don't know if positioning was expected to be part of the pattern.

```
" ".join([res.group("first"), res.group("last")]) # 'Marvin Klein'
```

Or, numerically:

```
" ".join([res.group(2), res.group(1)]) # 'Marvin Klein'
```

Comment: This gets me the groups. But unfortunately I need it as plain Regex which returns me the name. There is no way to use a programming language in my case to filter by groups.

Comment: How is the regex going to be run?  Also, does the result need to be ordered Vorname Name?

Comment: The Regex is run by a Software called ecoDMS which just runs my entered Regex expression to find a value on a document. Yes the Result should be ordered. First the name after Vorname and then the name after name.

Comment: I don't know if that's easy to do without grouping or substitution.  Can you do something similar as the following page shows using ecoDMS? -> https://www.tutorials.de/threads/regex-thema.407521/post-2111376

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I can simple enter two seperate regex expressions into the software in the required order.